# Virtualbox: can't ssh from host to guest

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

When I try to ssh from the host to the guest, the connection is refused.
How do I set this up?

- I have a Win7 host and an Ubuntu server 14.04 guest.
- I have 2 interfaces set up, `eth0` in NAT and `eth1` in host-only with a  static IP (192.168.56.56).
- I can ping the guest from the host on that IP.
- I can ssh from the guest to itself with `ssh user@192.168.56.56`

However when I try to execute `ssh user@192.168.56.56` from the host, I get connection refused.

---

**Notes and updates**:

- It's not a firewall issue. I disabled the firewall on the guest and I still can't connect.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue.

Comment: @jlliagre how do I find out?

Comment: The simplest way is to temporarily turn off your firewall

Comment: @jlliagre go on...

Comment: Hmm, you don't know if you have a firewall in the first place?

Comment: @jlliagre assume I know absolutely nothing

Comment: Then you need to ask a new question, "How do I know if I have a firewall running on my Windows 7 machine and how do I turn it off if it is the case?"

Comment: ok.  It's not a firewall issue.  I disabled the firewall and I still can't connect

Comment: Did you reboot (both the host and guest)?

Comment: not the host, but I can ssh to virtually anywhere else, including an OL VM running on the same host in VMware.

Comment: Hi time to work! ;-) 1. What is the output of `route -n` from the guest?  2. Try to do `ssh` from the host to its IP (assuming you have no ssh deamon up on the host you may reach your guest, read the current Ip from ipconfig if windows). 3. Check for the configuration of the ssh deamon in the host.

Comment: [`route -n` output](http://pastebin.com/9qY9MXwB).  ssh to the host gave the same connection refused (it's a windows host with no ssh daemon).

Comment: Are guest and host on the same subnet? If not try to switch from NAT to Bridged the other one. It should put the 2 in the same subnetwork... Ps> "route -n" seems to be ok.

Comment: They are not, but switching to bridged didn't help.

Comment: i was under the impression that the host-only adapter should provide host to guest communication.  It's clear that the guest is accessible from the host on that ip, i just can't ssh

Comment: I see you _ping_ that IP. Now I see better you said _"refused connection"_: check in the guest `/var/log/auth.log`. Better with `grep sshd.*Did /var/log/auth.log | less`. You can take some hints more from the verbose output of ssh (if you can have one). Switching from NAT to Bridget was suggested to overcome some restrictions eventually present in the guest ssh configuration.

Comment: That grep returned nothing.  I tailed the log and tried another ssh and nothing was written to it.

Comment: You disabled the firewall on the guest?? I was expecting a firewall to be present on the Windows 7 host, not on the Ubuntu guest. Also, please add `ifconfig -a`, `netstat -an | grep 22` and (Win7) `ipstat /all` outputs to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannnot comment here as yet.

Down you interfaces in Ubuntu, then Up only Eth1 and try to connect again from host.

Also, show content of your /etc/network/interfaces.

If you try to connect as a root check if root login is permitted in sshd settings.

What can you see using telnet from host? I mean

```
telnet 192.168.56.56 22
```